# IICS: multiple queries into one flat file

Tags: etl, informatica, soql, informatica-cloud, iics

I'm just learning my way around Informatica's IICS and wanted to do something that I figured should be simple: I'm trying to get record counts from multiple Salesforce databases into a single CSV. I can't do this with a single SOQL query, so my idea was to have multiple sources - each of them has a "select count() from ..." type of query, like so

[image]

I have one of these for Account, Contact, Campaign, User, etc. Each of these returns a single number(integer), like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get all of these results into one CSV? Ideally it would have one column Account with the record count, then a column Contact with its record count, etc. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be easier if you had the data in rows with columns for entity and count. Add the entity name as a calculated column to each query and then union them all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. All you need is to add a [Union Transformation](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration/current-version/transformations/union-transformation.html) to tell the process you want all three sources combined into a single dataset. Then simply connect the union with your target.

There is also [full example](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration/current-version/transformations/union-transformation/union-transformation-example.html) well explained available in IICS docs.